# Android Camera NullPointerException

Tags: android, камера

При старте записи вылетает ошибка NullPointerException на методе mCamera.unlock().

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Разблокируем камеру

    mCamera.unlock();

    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Устанавливаем источники аудио и видеоинформации

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Если API>=8, устанавливаем CamcorderProfile

    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Определяем выходную директорию

    mOutputFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraExample/videoout.mp4";

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFileName);

    // Step 5: Установка preview для записи

    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Подготовка MediaRecorder-а и обработка возможных ошибок

    try {

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());

        releaseMediaRecorder();

        return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());

        releaseMediaRecorder();

        return false;

    }

    return true;

}
```

Получение экземпляра Camera

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // попытка получить Camera экземпляр
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Камера недоступна (или не существует)
    }
    return c;
}

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);

    // Получаем доступ к эеземпляру камеры – код этого метода приведен выше

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Создаем Preview и помещаем его на Layout.

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
    Button captureButton = (Button)findViewById(id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    preview.addView(mPreview);

}
```

Подозреваю, что это происходит из-за того, что в onCreate уже вызывается Camera.open().
Но не могу его там не вызывать, потому что там устанавливаю CameraPreview.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: [Синглтон](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) обычно реализовывают по-другому. А вообще, метод `getCameraInstance` у вас может вернуть `null`, почему вы не проверяете возвращаемое значение в `prepareVideoRecorder`?

Comment: Видимо потому, что метод open, будучи вызванным без параметров возвращает "первую заднюю камеру". Если такой нет (например на Nexus 7), то возвратит null.

Comment: VladD, да действительно getCameraInstance возвращает null. Убрал его и он вернул:

android.hardware.Camera@413d9860
prepare: surface=0xbc4a38 (identity=817)
android.hardware.Camera@413d9860

Странно, что камера вернулась дважды. И теперь ошибка такая:

java.lang.RuntimeException: unlock failed

Почему unlock не срабатывает?

Comment: Разобрался - завернул unlock в try{} catch{}